# converting SQL query to Relational Algebra: EMP, DEPT, MANAGER

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

What is the relational algebra for these 2 SQL statements?

```sql
SELECT EMP.*
     , DEPT.DEPTNAME
     , DEPT.BUILDING
     , MANAGER.NAME DEPT_MANAGER
  FROM DEPT DEPARTMENT
     , EMPLOYEES EMP
     , EMPLOYEES MANAGER
 WHERE DEPT.DEPTMANAGERID = MANAGER.EMPID
   AND EMP.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO;

SELECT rep.repname SalesRep
     , prod.productno ProdID
     , prod.productname Name
     , prod.productdesc ProdDesc
     , prod.units Unit
     , prod.productprice Price
     , paint.*
     , chem.*
     , feed.*
     , sup.repname Supervisor
  FROM products prod
     , salesreps rep
     , salesreps sup
     , paintproducts paint
     , chemicalproducts chem
     , animalfeedproducts feed
 WHERE rep.salesrepid = prod.productsalesrepid
   AND rep.supervisor = sup.salesrepid (+)
   AND prod.productno = paint.productno (+)
   AND prod.productno = chem.productno (+)
   AND prod.productno = feed.productno (+);
```

I tried this this for the first one:

```
  π emp.*, dept.deptname, dept.building, manager.name
    (Department ⋈ deptmanagerid = empid Employees)
× (Employee ⋈ Emp.Deptno = Dept.DeptNo Department)
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert the queries and got stuck? It would be better if you showed us what you tried and why you are having problems, then just asking for people to convert it for you.

Answer (score 0):

For your first query, for the manager's info:

```
SELECT MANAGER.*
 , DEPT.DEPTNAME
 , DEPT.BUILDING
 , DEPT_MANAGER
FROM DEPT DEPARTMENT
 , EMPLOYEES MANAGER
WHERE DEPT.DEPTMANAGERID = MANAGER.EMPID
AND MANAGER.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO;
```

If you want the employees of the manager, you have to use two tables like you intended in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The query translation between SQL and relational algebra is straightforward: the `from` clause is Cartesian product, the `where` clause lists restrictions (aka selections), and the `select` clause is projection, applied in the order described. These kinds of relational queries are called SPJ (select-project-join) or SPC in the literature.

The translation between the query with outer join and relational algebra doesn't make sense: contrary to [wikipedia RA page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Left_outer_join_.28.E2.9F.95.29), the outer join (let alone the one written in Oracle proprietary error-prone syntax) is not a part of standard relational algebra.